# What's a good way of protecting password on a plain text executable script?

Tags: command-line, scripts, encryption, steam

I am managing a few dedicated game servers on a Ubuntu server 14.04 machine. These games are downloaded and updated by the [SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD) tool, which for some games, requires login from the command line arguments, which are plain readable text.

I created a few scripts to automate the processes of updating the servers every time the machine restarts, which are run by the user's `cron`.

**Anyway, long story short:** I need to find a way to securely store a password in a executable script. I'm thinking of storing just the encrypted password and somehow decrypt it before plugging it to the `steamcmd` arguments, and of course set user permissions to let just the owner user read it (or even just execute, is it possible?). Any advice on that?

Comment: Is a valid method to ask the password when the program runs?

Comment: Not really, this should be 100% automated. This script is run twice per day, every 12h, so asking for the password is out of question.

Comment: Who are you protecting the password from? Does the user enter the password once per session/login, or is it forever stored in the script? Is it separate from the login passphrase, or encrypted with the login passphrase? Look into the kernel's key management facility i.e. `keyctl`, or maybe a keyfile stored encrypted &/or ramdisk/tmpfs

Answer (score 1):

1. For highest security, you would want to store the password in only one place, that is your mind. But this is not a option as you want to completely automate the process and this method will require you to enter the password everytime.
2. You might have a look at hashing encrypting technology like `gpg`. But even here, you will need to remember and enter a passphrase, so bad option.
3. You might think that you will store the password in encrypted text file and hard-code the passphrase. But that isn't going to make any change.

The best midway solution would be,

- Save the password in a simple or encrypted text file. Make the file readable only by root user. Otherwise, just hard-code it into the program.
- Make the program readable and executable only by root user.
- If possible, deny all access to the computer by other users or guests.
- Encrypt your partition, so even an attempt to reset root password won't help to read your files.